# Spring mongoDB map reduce key string

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mapreduce

Im doing a map reduce in mongo as it follows:

```
List<Measurement> lista = new ArrayList<Measurement>();
    String map = "function Map() {emit(this.emissionType,this.avgValue); }";
    String reduce = "function Reduce (key, values) { var size = values.length; var result = (Array.sum(values))/size; return result;    }";
    Query query = new Query();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
    Date date = cal.getTime();

    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("sensor.$id").is(sensorId).andOperator(Criteria.where("date").gt(date)));

    MapReduceResults<Measurement> result = null;
    try{    
          result = template.mapReduce(query,"measurements", map, reduce, Measurement.class);
        }catch(Exception excep){
                excep.printStackTrace();
        }

    Iterator itr = result.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        lista.add((Measurement) element);
    }
```

What i want to do is to group by emissionType and get for each one its average value.

And with the reduce function I pretend to get the total average of all the averages.

Finally all the results i want to get must be of the last 24 hours.

The problem comes when I execute that and it doesnt return anything

Comment: The output class needs to be something that suits the output requirements of mapReduce. Is it? It looks like you are trying to re-use a standard class.

Comment: According to API is ok: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#mapReduce(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)

Comment: Yes. But the **output class** needs to match the fields in your output. That is different from the class being used to query. You only have key and value in the output.